# Show background depth on button panel

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

Any clue about how to create below kind of dashboard? I use [angular fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome).

I can create simple `play button` like so:

```
 <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="onPlay()">
            <fa-icon [icon]="faPlayCircle" size="4x"></fa-icon>
 </a>
```

But How to do this? I would like to know about how to give the depth on the background like so on the image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can reach great results only with CSS. Here is a small sample only using HTML and CSS.

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #3D3D3D;
}

.container-play {
  position: relative;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #f0f;
}

.holder-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 37px);
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#333333, #686868);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: 7px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#41825C, #1B4F2C);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.play i {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="container-play">
    <div class="holder-play">
      <div class="play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good. But how can I show the depth as shown on the image (`red` arrow area)?

Comment: Hey @Sampath, I updated the code adding a more accurate effect. You can improve that. Basically, the secret is to know how to use some CSS keys as `box-shadow` with the attribute `inset`, and `linear-gradient`.